# The application turn off after 1~2 minutes

Tags: heroku

I was trying to use Heroku to get my bot online 24/7, but there was a problem that my procfile is not recognized (at least I think that's it). I wrote in the procfile:
`worker: npm start`
however, I didn't see anything like it on Heroku's Dyno tab. If anyone can help me, my entire code is up here: *https://github.com/Kasashii/FramedataGarotada*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the procfile to Procfile, as specified by [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: Excellent, glad to help